# -X flag (X11 Forwarding) does not appear to work in Windows

Tags: ssh, x11, windows, openssh

I am using Open SSH (OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014) in Windows 8.1. 
X11 Forwarding does not appear to be working. The DISPLAY environment variable does not appear to be set.

For example, if I use BitVise or Putty to connect, and run env, I see:

```
[marko@vm:~]$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=6
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.174 61102 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=marko
MAIL=/var/mail/marko
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD=/home/marko
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/marko
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LOGNAME=marko
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.174 61102 192.168.1.64 22
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

If I instead use OpenSSH (ssh -X marko@vm):

```
[marko@vm:~]$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=8
TERM=cygwin
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.174 61150 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=marko
MAIL=/var/mail/marko
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD=/home/marko
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/marko
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LOGNAME=marko
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.174 61150 192.168.1.64 22
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you set `DISPLAY` environment variable on the client?  I'm not sure which shell you are using, but with Bourne shell derivative (like bash), please try:

```
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0
ssh -X marko@vm
```

Or if you're using cmd.exe:

```
set DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0
ssh -X marko@vm
```

Or if you're using powershell.exe:

```
$env:DISPLAY = '127.0.0.1:0'
ssh -X marko@vm
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. `set DISPLAY=anything` followed by `ssh -X user@remote` returns `CreateProcessW failed error:2 ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: No such file or directory Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`Unsetting the environment variable with `set DISPLAY=` allows me to ssh successfully again, but without working X forwarding. It doesn't make any sense to me that setting DISPLAY should cause the software to ask for my password this way. https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1088 https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1088

Comment: You probably found out already, but there's a workaround for this by creating an empty file with the path `C:\dev\tty`. The dev who fixed the bug wrote an explanation for it: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/966#issuecomment-461968005

Answer (score 20):

When you run `ssh -X remotehost` and you get `DISPLAY=localhost:10` presented to the remote host. `ssh` listens on that port and forwards traffic back to the calling system, using its original value of `DISPLAY` to determine the server address.

It's probable that on your local system you've got `DISPLAY=:0`. Or if you haven't, that's what it's being defaulted as. This instructs the local system to use the UNIX domain socket to communicate with the display. Unfortunately `Xming` on Windows doesn't set up that UNIX domain socket so your `ssh` X11 forwarding fails with this sort of error:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ ssh -X remotehost xlogo
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

The fix - at least as far as `Xming` goes - is fairly simple. Modify the `DISPLAY` variable to reference a listening TCP socket rather than a UNIX domain socket.

```
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0
$ ssh -X remotehost xlogo
```

You might have to adapt your `Xming` configuration to listen on the local TCP port 6000. Here is how I start `Xming`:

```
Xming.exe :0 -clipboard -multiwindow
```

And here is evidence to confirm that `Xming` is listening on port tcp/6000:

```
$ netstat -na | grep ':6000 .*LISTEN'
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Comment: Any idea why `DISPLAY=:0` works fine on WSL+XMing for `xeyes`, but not for `ssh -X`? Does `ssh -X` interpret $DISPLAY differently from other local X11 clients? Do other X11 clients fall back automatically to `localhost:0` but `ssh -X` does not?

Comment: On `man X` it says that the empty hostname in DISPLAY=:0 means "The most efficient local transport will be chosen." So may be `ssh -X` uses a different algorithm to do that compared to say `xeyes`?

Comment: @MarkusKuhn perhaps WSL+Xming is different to Cygwin+Xming. I see that I'm now using `DISPLAY=:0` and `ssh -X` forwards it happily.

Answer (score 15):

This work for me:
Set environment variable in PowerShell:

```
$env:DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:0"
```

Then `ssh -Y`

Answer (score 4):

With ssh in Windows10 and Xming, I seem to get "good"(?) results with:

```
set DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

and creating an object C:\dev\tty e.g. with

```
mkdir \dev
echo x > \dev\tty
```

and using `ssh -Y` (not `ssh -X`).

Comment: See also/instead, either/both https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1088 https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/966

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command in Powershell:

setx DISPLAY "localhost:0.0"

Restart powershell afterwards (very important!)

Connect using powershell with ssh -Y username@computer

NOTE:
Make sure you ssh using -Y to enable remote graphics

Comment: I'd like to explain what makes the *setx* command the best choice: it works in *cmd* and in *powershell*, this command provides the only command-line or programmatic way to directly and *permanently* set system environment values; but: variables set with setx variables are available in future command windows only, not in the current command window.